Unable to Connet to Azure Gen 2 Store with Power BI
Whenever I attempt to connect to Azure GEN 2 (ADLSv2) with Power BI I'm immediately get the message: "Access to the resource is forbidden". I am not asked for SAS keys or tokens or anything


Can someone let me know how to resolve this issue?

Is it in a VNet or firewall? It should prompt you after this to login with your ID or account key. It looks like it is not allowing network access to it

Hi @jon, when I first attempted to access with my url storage account it did indeed prompt me for my login with my ID or account key. I put in the wrong account key. When I attempted to insert the correct account key I got the "Access to the resource is forbidden". I should mention that I don't have any problems with trying to access our blob storage account. Just ADLS Gen 2.

You can go to the connections/data source settings and delete the gen 2 reference and connect again with the right key.

I fixed the problem by connecting with dfs instead of blob.

You have given the endpoint for azure blob storage in azure data lake connector. That is the reason you are getting the error. In order to get the datalake's endpoint from the azure portal, follow the below steps.

Click the data lake storage account in the azure portal.

Select the endpoint under settings as shown in the below image.




Under data lake storage, copy the URL



Paste this URL in azure data lake gen2 power bi connector.

